# Previously working Firebase Function Fails Now When Deleting Old Data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase function that worked previously, but upon deploying it today, I get an error message that says this:

```
This request would cause too many functions to be triggered.
```

And it fails and doesn't delete the data.  Any idea why?

Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Cut off time. Child nodes older than this will be deleted.
const CUT_OFF_TIME = 180 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 180 Days in milliseconds.

/**
 * This database triggered function will check for child nodes that are older than the
 * cut-off time. Each child needs to have a `timestamp` attribute.
 */
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
      const ref = event.data.ref.parent; // reference to the items
      const now = Date.now();
      const cutoff = now - CUT_OFF_TIME;
      const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('time').endAt(cutoff);
      return oldItemsQuery.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        // create a map with all children that need to be removed
        const updates = {};
        snapshot.forEach(child => {
          updates[child.key] = null;
        });
        // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
        return ref.update(updates);
      });
    });
```

Comment: If you're seeing problems deploying code, contact Firebase support directly.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this fixed by changing the trigger from an OnWrite to an OnCreate.  I guess OnWrite (since it deals with deletes, changes, and adds) was being invoked too many times by all the deletes the script was doing.